# Filter groups where all rows in a column are the same dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I was trying to do something kind of simple. My dataframe looks like this:

```
ID    value
1       a
2       b
2       c
3       d
3       d
4       e
4       e
4       e
```

What I wanted to do is to filter groups with more than one row and where all the values in the `value` column are the same:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() > 1 & all(mysterious_condition))
```

So `mysterious_condition` is what I'm lacking. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
ID    value
3       d
3       d
4       e
4       e
4       e
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID, value) %>% filter(n() > 1)`

Comment: Base R: `df[ave(seq(nrow(df)), df[,c("ID","value")], FUN = length) > 1,]`

Comment: Just noticed interpreting value as a group worked and now saw you suggested the same @r2evans. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans, if there is a group with three rows of values c("a", "a", "b"), grouping by id and value will keep the "a" rows and only drop the "b" row. However, the entire group should be removed if I understand the OP's request correctly.

Comment: @mt1022 That's a good point. In my actual case the maximum number of rows was actually two, so it wouldn't matter, but in that case akrun's answer is more general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `n_distinct` to check for the count of unique elements

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(n() >1, n_distinct(value) == 1) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
     ID value
  <int> <chr>
1     3 d    
2     3 d    
3     4 e    
4     4 e    
5     4 e
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), value = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```